# AccessVBA メインのアクセスから別のアクセスを開くときにフォームを開かせない方法

Tags: vba, ms-access, form

お世話になります。

Access2010にて、VBAで他のアクセスを開くときに、OpenCurrentDatabaseで開こうとするの
ですが、呼び出される方のアクセスに、指定のフォームを開く設定がされているとフォームが
開いてしまいますが、これを通常開くときにシフトキーで開くように、設定などを無効にして
開きたいのですが、その方法をお教えください。

第一引数にExclusiveというものがあったので、これをFalseにしてみましたが、できませんでした。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

こんにちは。

OpenCurrentDatabaseでは、起動オプションを無効にして開くことはできなさそうですね。
第一引数のExclusiveは排他で開くかどうかなので、関係ないです。

ちょっと強引な感じですが、SendInput関数を使えばできます。

参考URL
http://blogwizhook.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-151.html